# Can not deserialize instance of com.advice.domain.family.Income out of START_ARRAY token↵ at

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, spring-boot

I have two classes, one is `Income` and the other is `Salary`. I have a json which looks like this.

```
"income" : [
    {
        "_id" : 271234.0, 
        "type" : "salary", 
        "amount" : 100000.0, 
        "inception" : "11/8/1986", 
        "endsOn" : "11/8/2030", 
        "salary" : {
            "ctc" : 200000.0, 
            "basic" : 32000.0, 
            "pf" : 14000.0, 
            "gratuity" : 55000.0, 
            "paci" : 5000.0, 
            "sa" : 50000.0, 
            "mediclaim" : 50000.0
        }
    }
]
```

Class `Income`:

```
public class Income {

    public static final String INCOME = "income";

    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 30)
    private String type;

    @Size(max = 10)
    private int amount;

//  @Size(max = 50)
    private String inception =null;

//  @Size(max = 10)
    private String endsOn =null;

    private Salary salary;
}
```

Class `Salary`:

```
public class Salary {

    private int ctc;  

    private int basic;

    private int pf;

    private int gratuity;

    private int paci;

    private int sa;

    private int mediclaim;

}
```

I am hiding all constructors, setters and getters for Stackoverflow but they are in my code. I want to parse Json to Object using `ObjectMapper` from an URL using this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{cUsrId}/lc/{lcId}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<?> addNewIncome( @PathVariable Long cUsrId, @PathVariable Long lcId,@RequestBody List<Income> income) {

    log.debug("REST request to save Profile by id: {},  lcId: {},lcId: {}, income: {}",  cUsrId,lcId,income);
    int success = engagementService.saveNewIncome(cUsrId, lcId, income);
    if(success ==0){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }else{
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> "Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of
>   com.advice.domain.family.Income out of START_ARRAY token↵ at [Source:
>   java.io.PushbackInputStream@3d3298f9; line: 1, column: 2] (through
>   reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of com.advice.domain.family.Income out of
>   START_ARRAY token↵ at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3d3298f9;
>   line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])"

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight disconnect. Your JSON is as presented is actually not an income object, so it is right in yelling at you for that. The income object is only this portion of the JSON string:

```
{
        "_id" : 271234.0, 
        "type" : "salary", 
        "amount" : 100000.0, 
        "inception" : "11/8/1986", 
        "endsOn" : "11/8/2030", 
        "salary" : {
            "ctc" : 200000.0, 
            "basic" : 32000.0, 
            "pf" : 14000.0, 
            "gratuity" : 55000.0, 
            "paci" : 5000.0, 
            "sa" : 50000.0, 
            "mediclaim" : 50000.0
        }
    }
```

If you post just the following you should avoid the issue since it is in fact an array of income objects:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : 271234.0, 
        "type" : "salary", 
        "amount" : 100000.0, 
        "inception" : "11/8/1986", 
        "endsOn" : "11/8/2030", 
        "salary" : {
            "ctc" : 200000.0, 
            "basic" : 32000.0, 
            "pf" : 14000.0, 
            "gratuity" : 55000.0, 
            "paci" : 5000.0, 
            "sa" : 50000.0, 
            "mediclaim" : 50000.0
        }
    }
]
```

You can test this in a unit test with the following use of the Jackson ObjectMapper:

```
Income[] incomes = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonAsString,Income[].class);
```

Which you can get from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```